# I can't aim or fire a bow in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can't aim or fire a bow in Minecraft on my pc computer. I can use other items such as a fishing pole, so I don't think it's a 'Use item' issue.

All other things work fine, like opening doors, magic carpet, etc. A fellow gamer suggested I uninstall and and re-download and install the game. I am wondering if there are any other possibilities before I go to all that trouble. 
The last time I tried to download something, it changed my desktop and search engine and it was a pain restoring it all. That was 2 months ago, so not what's wrong now.

Comment: I may sound like Captain Obvious here, but do you have arrows in your inventory?

Comment: @SpiceWeasel Consider posting that as an answer.

Comment: If you install something and it changes something you didn't expect it to change, that sounds like a virus. You should let your computer get checked out by an expert. Even if you don't notice anything right now, it can still do evil things in the background. And only download Minecraft from minecraft.net, never anywhere else.

Comment: Also, what? "Magic carpet"?

Answer (score 5):

### You need to have arrows in your Inventory.

Even with a Bow with the [Infinity](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#Infinity) enchantment, you still need at least one arrow<sup>1</sup> in your inventory - it won't work if they are in a shulker box or anything like that.

<sup>1. [Tipped arrows](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Arrow#Tipped_arrows) do not work with Infinity</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Things to check

- Do you have arrows in your inventory?
- Are your controls changed?
- Try a different mouse
- Uninstall that program that made you lose that function
- Check I the new program is running in the background
- Re-Install Minecraft

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you are using a legitimate version of the game from [Minecraft.net](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/store/) because the Mojang download shouldn't change your default search engine. An illegitimate version can have many glitches and may even have given you one or many viruses.